# Crop password protected pdf in C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, itext

I need to develop Windows Forms Application where user will select a PDF(password protected) from OpenFileDialog then my application should crop that PDF and save it.

The PDF Files are of same format and cropping dimension is also fix.
(How can i get dimension from PDF file?)

I am new to itextsharp library can any one help me in this please.

Comment: Search some from itext..

Comment: What have you tried, what stopped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] password = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pdfPass);
        PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(src, password);
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(src, password);
        int n = reader1.NumberOfPages;
        PdfDictionary pageDict1;
        PdfDictionary pageDict2;
        PdfRectangle rect1;
        PdfRectangle rect2;
        //For Old Aadhar Card
        if (PdfType == "Old")
        {
            rect1 = new PdfRectangle(10, 50, 300, 270);
            rect2 = new PdfRectangle(290, 50, 590, 270);
        }
        else 
        {
            rect1 = new PdfRectangle(10, 50, 500, 270);
            rect2 = new PdfRectangle(290, 50, 590, 270);
        }
        //For New Aadhar Card
        //PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(10, 40, 570, 270);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            pageDict1 = reader1.GetPageN(i);
            pageDict1.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect1);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            pageDict2 = reader2.GetPageN(i);
            pageDict2.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect2);
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper stamper1 = new PdfStamper(reader1, new FileStream(@"D:\testpdfnew1.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            PdfStamper stamper2 = new PdfStamper(reader2, new FileStream(@"D:\testpdfnew2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            stamper1.Close();
            stamper2.Close();
            reader1.Close();
            reader2.Close();
        }
```

I wrote above code it works for my question.

Comment: How to create in two pages? I mean front and back